# Android Studio Build Fails "Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'."

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin

I'm getting this error and I think I understand where it's coming from but I don't understand the problem. Detailed summary of the error I am getting.

```
> Task :app:kaptDebugKotlin
C:\Users\matan\AndroidStudioProjects\RoomTut\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\com\example\roomtut\data\MarkerDao.java:13: error: Type of the parameter must be a class annotated with @Entity or a collection/array of it.
    kotlin.coroutines.Continuation<? super kotlin.Unit> p1);
                                                        ^C:\Users\matan\AndroidStudioProjects\RoomTut\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\com\example\roomtut\data\MarkerDao.java:11: error: Not sure how to handle insert method's return type.
    public abstract java.lang.Object addMarker(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
                                     ^[WARN] Incremental annotation processing requested, but support is disabled because the following processors are not incremental: androidx.room.RoomProcessor (DYNAMIC).

> Task :app:kaptDebugKotlin FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithoutKotlincTask$KaptExecutionWorkAction
   > java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 32s
29 actionable tasks: 9 executed, 20 up-to-date
```

I understand there's a problem in my marker dao but to me the annotation looks fine you can see below and also the link to my repo for the full project - https://github.com/M-J-Y-21/room-test

```
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.room.Dao
import androidx.room.Insert
import androidx.room.OnConflictStrategy
import androidx.room.Query

@Dao
interface MarkerDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    suspend fun addMarker(marker: Marker)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM marker_table ORDER BY id ASC")
    fun readAllData(): LiveData<List<Marker>>
}
```

You can see how I've annotated my marker class below

```
import androidx.room.Entity
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey

@Entity(tableName = "marker_table") data class Marker(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id: Int,
    val title: String,
    val location: String,
    val colour: String
)
```

My database class below

```
import android.content.Context
import androidx.room.Database
import androidx.room.Room
import androidx.room.RoomDatabase

@Database(entities = arrayOf(Marker::class), version = 1, exportSchema = false)
abstract class MarkerDatabase: RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun markerDao(): MarkerDao

    companion object {
        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: MarkerDatabase? = null

        fun getDatabase(context: Context): MarkerDatabase{
            val tempInstance = INSTANCE
            if (tempInstance != null) {
                return tempInstance
            }
            synchronized(this) {
                val instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context.applicationContext,
                    MarkerDatabase::class.java,
                    "marker_database"
                ).build()
                INSTANCE = instance
                return instance
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try change you code like: ` suspend fun addMarker(marker: Marker): Long` or  ` suspend fun addMarker(marker: Marker): Int`  i.e. add return type. You have an error message: MarkerDao.java:11: error: Not sure how to handle insert method's return type.

Comment: I've tried adding that return type as a Long and then Int both still fail this is my basic build error message when I try with an Int - `> Task :app:kaptDebugKotlin
C:\Users\matan\AndroidStudioProjects\RoomTut\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\com\example\roomtut\data\MarkerDao.java:13: error: Type of the parameter must be a class annotated with @Entity or a collection/array ^C:\Users\matan\AndroidStudioProjects\RoomTut\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\com\example\roomtut\data\MarkerDao.java:11: error: Not sure how to handle insert method's return type.`

Comment: Please add imports to code snippets

Comment: Done Artem, please see the updated version

Comment: Did you add your `Marker` Entity  to your database definition like in sample https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room#database ?

Comment: Yes I did @Artem you can see my database class above you can also see my github repo for the whole project - https://github.com/M-J-Y-21/room-test

Comment: Did you solve errors with  MarkerDao ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see your project uses different versions of `androidx.room` dependencies, for example:

```
"androidx.room:room-runtime:2.3.0"
"androidx.room:room-compiler:2.2.5"
```

You should use similar versions for all `androidx.room`'s artifacts. [Please look at sample with more right approach](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room#setup):

```
dependencies {
...
    def room_version = "2.3.0"

    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version" 

...
}
```

When I changed all versions of `androidx.room`'s to `2.3.0` all starts work fine. And don't forget change return type for `addMarker`:

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
suspend fun addMarker(marker: Marker) // OK

@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
suspend fun addMarker(marker: Marker): Long // OK

@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
suspend fun addMarker(marker: Marker): Int // ERROR
```

How I was looking for a problem:

1. Check return type on `@Insert` method(see above).
2. Check argument's type and annotation of insert method(`@Entity`).
3. Check imports: IDE can automatically add import class or Annotation with similar name but from other package.
4. [Check setup of database](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room#database).
5. [Check project dependencies](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room#setup)([or other doc's sample](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room#declaring_dependencies)).

P.S. Your implementation of singleton by `MarkerDatabase.Companion.getDatabase()` is wrong :( Please Use double-check locking algorithm , or make all method as synchronized or try to adapt kotlin's `lazy` for your case.

Comment: @M-J -Y Please see PR with fix https://github.com/ardmn/room-test/pull/1 u can pull my brach and merge it to your repo.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help my gradle finally builds successfully now :) Tried to merge the request weirdly github didn't let me as it said I didn't have permission. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @M-J-Y You can clone my repo and then merge my branch to your remote. And if my answer was helpful for you pleas mark it as accepted.

Comment: I've already made the appropriate fixes and added a few more commits on the repo so I think it's a bit late, but anyway thanks for the help and I've accepted your answer.